# Как цикл for заставить итерировать изменненый список заного, который был изменнем внутри цикла for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for

После того как происходит вырезка числа и арифметического знака по индексу, происходит удаления тех же символов, по тому же индексу, но счет цикла `for` не начинает сначала списка `term_list`, как сделать так, чтобы список `term_list`, а именно показатели `i` и `n` начинали итерацию сначала обновленного списка `term_list`?

```
term_list = ['2', '3', '+', '2', '6', '-', '2', '1', '*', '2', '/', '2', '.', '2']
  
# Список чисел и ариф.знаков строки ввода
Input_line_numbers = []

print(term_list, '\n')
# Создание списка с конкатенированными числами и ариф.знаками
for i, n in enumerate(term_list):
    print('Я индекс: ', i, ' - Я число: ', n, '\n')
    if n in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
        print('Нашел арифметическое действие: ', n)
        print('До: ', term_list)
        print('До: ', Input_line_numbers, '\n')
        # Делаем вырезку в отдельный список от первого знака и 
        # до знака арифметики
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:i]))
        # Удоляем часть списка от первого знака и до знака арифметики
        del term_list[0:i]
        # Вырезаем сам знак арифметики
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0]))
        # Удоляем знак арифметики
        del term_list[0]
        print('После: ', term_list)
        print('После: ', Input_line_numbers, '\n')

# Вызераем в отдельный список последнее число
Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:]))   
# Удоляем последнее число из списка
del term_list[0:]

print(Input_line_numbers)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно, например, сделать словарь где ключи - индексы, а значения - значения массива по индексу

Comment: @BigCubeCat Идея хорошая, а возможно реализовать то что я описал в вопросе, используя именно список, который указан в вопросе?

Comment: "заного"? Серьезно?

Comment: @strawdog Что не так конкретно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, использовать функцию `copy()`, так же исключить функцию `enumerate()`, и искать индекс элементов списка, внутри цикла `for`

```
term_list = ['2', '3', '+', '2', '6', '-', '2', '1', '*', '2', '/', '2', '.', '2']
  
# Список чисел и ариф.знаков строки ввода
Input_line_numbers = []

print(term_list)
# Создание списка с конкатенированными числами и ариф.знаками
for n in term_list.copy():
    i = term_list.index(n)
    print('Я индекс: ', i, ' - Я число: ', n)
    if n in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
        print('Нашел арифметическое действие: ', n)
        print('До: ', term_list)
        print('До: ', Input_line_numbers)
        # Делаем вырезку в отдельный список от первого знака и 
        # до знака арифметики
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:i]))
        # Удоляем часть списка от первого знака и до знака арифметики
        del term_list[0:i]
        # Вырезаем сам знак арифметики
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0]))
        # Удоляем знак арифметики
        del term_list[0]
        print('После: ', term_list)
        print('После: ', Input_line_numbers)
        i = 0
# Вызераем в отдельный список последнее число
Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:]))   
# Удоляем последнее число из списка
del term_list[0:]

print(Input_line_numbers)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не ответ. Код приводится текстом, не заставляйте людей ломать глаза читая подобное.

Comment: @A K Прошу прощения, по запарке видимо не заметил, что можно добавить код, исправил. Не являлся ответом только из за того, что код был приведен как изображение?